# Operator equals overloading c++ apparently not working

Tags: c++

Can someone explain me why the `cout` doesn't get called here?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    int a = 1;

    Test &operator=(const Test &other) {
        cout << "overloading here" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};


int main() {
    Test t1;
    Test &t3 = t1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    Test &t3 = t1;
```

is creating a reference for `Test` and initiaizing that. `=` operator is not used there.
There are no `cout` other than inside `operator=`, so `cout` won't be called.

Note that

```
    Test t3 = t1;
```

(without `&`) will also not call `operator=` because this is an initialization of object and a constructor is used for that.

To use `operator=`, you should do like

```
    Test t3;
    t3 = t1;
```

Comment: Could you provide the constructor called by `Test& t3 = t1` ?

Comment: @AlbertoTiraboschi `Test(const Test& t) {}`

Comment: @AlbertoTiraboschi in that case no constructor is called as you do not create a new object.

Comment: @slava well, technically it's an object, just not an object of type Test..

Comment: MikeCAT, @Slava apparently `Test(const Test& t) {}` is called by `Test t3 = t1;` Therefore is there a way to overload `Test &t3 = t1;`? It is just a question out of curiosity. Thank you very much.

Comment: No. A reference is not a user-defined type, so it cannot have its operators overloaded.

Comment: @JHBonarius reference is not an object, it is an alias and no new object is created. In certain case language allows to create temporary objects and assign to references (not this case though) but still references themselves are not objects.

Comment: "Therefore is there a way to overload `Test &t3 = t1;`" no, there is no way, you create an alias to existing object, what you can do with alias is to use it like original object. In some cases you can "intercept" though, like `const A &ref = B{};`  but that a different story - you create temporary of type `A` from type `B` and you can "overload" that, but you cannot do anything with creation of the reference.

Comment: @slava that's implementation. It can become an alias. But if you pass it as a function parameter, it will take up space comparable to a pointer.

Comment: @JHBonarius yes and if you put it into structure it will take some space. But from language point of view that's an alias and you cannot differentiate it from the object it refers to. Is reference itself is an object or not matter of definitions, but I would say considering it as an object would create more misunderstanding than vice versa.

Comment: @slava you have a point. But I have a hardware background, building extreme minimal applications in very small processors. For me or would be important to know which objects requires what amount of memory. So it's probably a point of view/domain thing. But sorry for the off topic.

Comment: @JHBonarius I understand, but irony is that what you are describing - "which objects requires what amount of memory" is actually implementation, but what I said  is how it works on language level, not the vice versa.